# If I change ImageFIeld.upload_to parameter, should it move previously uploaded files upon migration?

Tags: django, database-migration

I have a Django model with

```
...
image = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to=settings.PHOTO_UPLOAD_TO)
...
```

I have changed the value of `settings.PHOTO_UPLOAD_TO`, but the files have remained where they were, and the database entries also don't seem to have changed. A newly added image is placed in the correct new location, but not the old ones. Is it an expected behaviour? Is there a way to migrate the image locations? I would like to slightly change the directory/URL structure of my project.

Answer (score 0):

The path of a `FileField`/`ImageField` is stored relative to `MEDIA_ROOT`, so if you want to move the files to the new `upload_to` folder, you're gonna need to put that in your migration yourself (like you suggested).

Comment: You mean, I need to program the move of the files and change of the database entries in the `migrations/00xx_yyy.py` file?

Comment: I would say better to separate model migration and data migration. You can create an empty migration via `./manage.py makemigrations youapp --empty`